# How to display query results in DataGridView using list<T>

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am currently learning how to code in C#. I was able to connect a MySQL database instance for the first time! In my code, I have made a SQL query and put the data in into a List. I want to display the data stored in the List into a DataGridView.

I have tried several different methods I have found online, but none of them seem to work. I have tried using a foreach loop, to display the results.

My code inside the class:

```
    public List<string>[] Select()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        //Create a list to store the result
        List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
        list[0] = new List<string>();
        list[1] = new List<string>();
        list[2] = new List<string>();

        //Open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                list[0].Add(dataReader["user_id"] + "");
                list[1].Add(dataReader["user_name"] + "");
                list[2].Add(dataReader["user_lastname"] + "");
            }

            //close Data Reader
            dataReader.Close();

            //close Connection
            this.CloseConnection();

            //return list to be displayed
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

And this is the code inside the form:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DBConnect test = new DBConnect();
            foreach (var item in test.Select())
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = item;
            }

        }
```

When I try to display the results, I get a table that only says 'length', each filled with a number.

Comment: Is this WinForms or Webforms?

Comment: You're updating dataGridView1.DataSource many times. You should remove the foreach loop and change the code to dataGridView1.DataSource = test.Select();. Let me know if it helps you

Comment: Classes are made to prevent just this type of cumbersome code, also a DataTable would work just fine to display the data.  You will also want to read up on how DBProvider objects are meant to work because opening and closing one connection is sub optimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use `DataTable` direclty you can assign that to `Datasource` of Gridview.

```
if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{     

  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
  sqlCmd.Connection = con;
  sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users";
  SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

  DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
  sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dtRecord;
}
```

If you want to fill on button click event, return the DataTable from `Select()` and in button click just set datasouce.